# User typing null terminator in scanf

Tags: c, input, scanf

Can a user type null terminator in an input, for which scanf is used, so the length of the input would be 0?

```
char msg[1000];
scanf("%1000s",msg); // the user would type nothing: '' or '\0'
```

Comment: For the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format `"%s"` there must be *some* non-space input. If you want optional input why not use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i can not use fgets, it has to be scanf

Comment: Then you have to live with the limitations of not being able to give a non-empty input.

Comment: Also remember that you can always do input redirection and feed whatever bytes you like to stdin of your program, unconstrained by console and shell interference. (What your standard library does with the input it sees is another question.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Using `fgets()` or `scanf()` is irrelevant to the question.  Both functions have the same issue when input includes a null character.  The _null character_ is a non-white-space.

Comment: To the OP: What is the *actual* problem that you want to solve? How to read *empty* input? Something else? Please [read about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On many systems, the answer is "Yes".

Usually, the magic sequence is <kbd>Control-@</kbd>.

The character code for @ is usually 64, one less the that of A (65).   Control-A is character code 1; one less is character code 0, aka `'\0'`.

Note that to get a zero-length input, you'd have to type the null byte as the first non-space character, and you would still need to hit return to enter the input.  Your program would find it hard to reliably identify what else was entered after the null byte.

Answer (score 4):

Some systems allow the terminal user to enter a NUL byte by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>@</kbd>.  `scanf()` would then store this byte into the destination array, but would most likely not consider this byte to constitute a word separator, so input parsing would continue until end of file or a whitespace character such as newline is entered.

There is no way to tell from the destination array if a NUL byte was stored after other characters, nor precisely how many further characters have been read after this NUL byte. But if `scanf()` returned `1` and `msg` has a zero length, the only possibility is that the user entered a NUL byte after a possibly empty sequence of whitespace characters.

This would also be the only possibility for `fgets()` to return an empty string when passed a destination array with a size greater than 1.

If input is read from a file instead of a terminal, it is always a possibility for the file to contain NUL bytes and care should be taken to avoid undefined behavior if it happens.  For example, here is a classic bug:

```
char msg[1000];
if (fgets(msg, sizeof msg, stdin)) {
    int len = strlen(msg);
    if (msg[len - 1] == '\n') {  // potential undefined behavior!
        msg[--len] = '\0'       // potential undefined behavior!
    }
    ...
}
```

Also note that your code has a flaw: the maximum number of characters to store into the destination should be `999`, not `1000`:

```
char msg[1000];
if (scanf("%999s",msg) == 1) {
    /* word was read from the user */
    if (*msg == '\0') {
        printf("user entered a NUL byte\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can a user type null terminator in an input, for which scanf is used, so the length of the input would be 0?

In addition to a user [*typing* in a null character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41245484/2410359), `stdin` could use re-directed input that contains null characters.

```
foo < data.bin
```

---

Detail: When the first character scanned is a *null character* or `'\0'`, it is read like any other character and saved like any other non-white-space character.  So the *length of input* is still more than 0, but the value reported by `strlen(msg)` is fooled by the embedded null character and returns zero.

`fgets()` has the same problem as `scanf()` in this regard: `strlen(msg)` does not *alway* report the number of characters read.

Non-standard [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) does return the number of characters read and is a way out of this.

---

[@Stargateur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245214/user-typing-null-terminator-in-scanf/41246509?noredirect=1#comment69694369_41246509) mentions using `"%n"` to store the number of characters saved in `msg`.  Perhaps like

```
char msg[1000 + 1];
int start, end;
if (1 == scanf(" %n%1000s%n", &start, msg, &end)) {
  printf("%d characters read\n", end - start);
}
```

IAC, we are trying to cope with a corner weakness of `scanf()` and family.  The best *read input* solution depends on additional factors, not mentioned by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it possible because `'\0'` is a non-white-space. [`scanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) will consider that is the end of the string. So `%s` can match a empty string.

You can use the `m` specifier to allocate a corresponding buffer to hold the input. Note this is POSIX 200112L standard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str;
    int n;
    if (scanf("%ms%n", &str, &n) == 1) {
      printf("I read %d character(s).\n", n);
      if (strlen(str) != 0) {
        printf("str = %s\n", str);
      }
      else {
        printf("str is empty");
      }
      free(str);
    }
    else {
      printf("The user enter nothing");
    }
}
```

Comment: `free(str);`?!?!  Where's the corresponding `malloc()`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle In [scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) see m modifier.

Comment: Nice.  I learned something new today.  Thanks.  (And no, I wasn't the downvoter.)

Comment: "Because a string is at least one char to scanf flag %s." --> Disagree.  The null character is a non-space so if the user enters `'\0'`, `'A'`, `'B'`, `'\n'`,  OP's `"%1000s"` will cause a `'\0'`, `'A'`, `'B'`, `'\0'` to be saved in `msg[]`.  `scanf()` returns 1 and `strlen(msg) == 0`.  `msg[]` does have at least 2 characters (something and an null character) written to it.  It just happens that the first character one is `'\0'` and `strlen()` does not report the number of characters written.

Comment: note that the `m` specifier is non-standard http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf, and `scanf can't return a empty string` is incorrect because you can use ctrl+@

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Oh indeed my bad http://ideone.com/Irq2IS. I will add that `m` specifier is POSIX 200112L and no C11.